# Exchange web services - Forward Email as Attachment

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm currently using Exchange Web Services in C#. I basically have a small application that reads emails from an inbox and process them.

I would like to forward those emails I receive as an attachment of an email. This attachment will be an outlook email that will include the original email (including its own attachments if any).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Not sure why I'm getting the down votes but it seems this is not possible as the EWS API does not provide such functionality

Comment: Any ideas to what?  What is your question?

Comment: Hi @NathanA. I read the emails from the inbox and they are EmailMessage type. I will like to take this EmailMessage and add it to a new EmailMessage as an attachment (including everything in it) and then send it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an ItemAttachment with EWS but you can't replicate fully what is possible in Outlook with MAPI. Eg with EWS you can create an ItemAttachment and then use the MIMEContent to create an attachment based on a current message as a workaround eg

```
            FolderId Inboxid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "target@domain.com");    
        ItemView InboxItemView = new ItemView(1);
        FindItemsResults<Item> inFiResuls = service.FindItems(Inboxid,InboxItemView);
        if(inFiResuls.Items.Count == 1){
            EmailMessage fwdMail = new EmailMessage(service);
            EmailMessage orgMail = (EmailMessage)inFiResuls.Items[0];
            PropertySet psPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
            psPropSet.Add(ItemSchema.MimeContent);
            orgMail.Load(psPropSet);
            ItemAttachment emAttach = fwdMail.Attachments.AddItemAttachment<EmailMessage>();
            emAttach.Item.MimeContent = orgMail.MimeContent;
            ExtendedPropertyDefinition pr_flags = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3591,MapiPropertyType.Integer);
            emAttach.Item.SetExtendedProperty(pr_flags,"1");
            emAttach.Name = orgMail.Subject;
            fwdMail.Subject = "see Attached";
            fwdMail.ToRecipients.Add("user@domain.com");
            fwdMail.Send();
        }
```

This however doesn't give full fidelity of all the mapi properties associated with a particular message as the MIMEContent is just that, for most normal email messages this isn't an issue however for a message with an attached Outlook Task or other TNEF attachment then you would loose these of attachments or for other properties like categories,flags you would loose these also (you could copy these manually if needed).

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks! This seems like the step in the right direction. 

Now, how would you add the originals recipients (including cc and bcc emails) in the attached email? Because when I open the attached email I only see the address the fwdMail was sent to (in your example would be "user@domain.com").

Comment: The recipients should be included in the MIME content that has always worked for me so I'm surprised if you say it doesn't work but you can access the attached message objects property via emAttach.Item . The BCC field will always be blank as this is an envelope field.

Comment: Is it possible that the version of Outlook that is handling the emails? Maybe the version of my Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices? I'm using v14.0.0.0

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference i would suggest you save the Mime Content as an EML file and see if you can open it locally eg just save the ByteArray as an EML file File.WriteAllBytes("c:\temp\test.eml", orgMail.MimeContent.Content);

Answer (score 0):

you can forward your email using this way. It first loads and reads the each emails with attachment who has "msg" extension. then forwards it to given address. see the below code

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = exchange.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, newItemView(50,50));

Item[] msgItems = findResults.Where(msgItem => msgItem.HasAttachments).ToArray();
EmailMessage msgInfo = null;

var fileExtensions = new List<string> { "msg", "MSG", "Msg" };

    foreach (MSEWS.Item msgItem  in msgItems )
    {
      msgInfo = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange, msgItem.Id);
      FileAttachment fa = msgInfo.Attachments[0] asFileAttachment;
      if (fileExtensions.Any(ext => ext.Contains(fa.Name.Substring(fa.Name.Length - 3))))                            
        {    
        fa.Load();
        ResponseMessage responseMessage = msgInfo.CreateForward();
        responseMessage.BodyPrefix = "messageBody";
        responseMessage.ToRecipients.Add("toAddress");
        responseMessage.Subject = "subject";
        responseMessage.SendAndSaveCopy();

        }    
    }
```